# Connecting to WinCE 5.0 Device - ActiveSync vs Windows Mobile Device Center

Tags: windows-ce, activesync

I have a single board computer running Windows CE 5.0 that's connected to a desktop via serial.  I'm updating the desktop from Windows 2000 to Windows 7 and as a result need to update from ActiveSync to Windows Mobile Device Center.  With WMDC, I am no longer able to make a partnership with the device or connect.

My question is - **are there any known changes to how repllog.exe (device side) interacts with WMDC vs ActiveSync (host side)**?

Maybe a better question - will WMDC even work with with Windows CE 5.0?  The system requirements listed [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14) don't show CE 5.0 as supported.

Nothing else in the setup has changed and the only thing I can guess is that the single board computer is no longer 'answering' or handling the connect event properly.

I don't have access to the build tools for creating the WinCE 5.0 image unfortunately, so I'm not sure if I can easily update to WMDC on the device side.

Also, the current registry values:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services]
"RasTimeoutResponseWait"=dword:00000032
"RasTimeoutPause"=dword:00000005
"ConnectTypesAllowed"=dword:00000008
"CheckPasswordTimeoutSeconds"=dword:00000014
"WaitV2TimeoutSeconds"=dword:00000004
"SerialPort"="COM1"
"HasUsbDevice"=dword:00000000
"SerialBaudRate"=dword:0001c200
"DeviceType"=""
"DeviceOemInfo"=""
"DeviceVersion"=dword:04401504
"DeviceProcessorType"=dword:00000000
"DeviceProcessor"=""
"DTPTNetworkType"="{0}"
"DisableIr"=dword:00000000
"GuestOnly"=dword:00000001
"InstalledDir"="C:\\Windows\\WindowsMobile"
"Dual-Home"=dword:00000000
"DisableCredentialSave"=dword:00000000
"MajorVersion"=dword:00000006
"MinorVersion"=dword:00000001
"CurrentPartnershipProtocol"=dword:00000003
"MinimumPartnershipProtocol"=dword:00000002
@=""
"BuildNumber"=dword:00001b35
"EulaRequired"=dword:06010000
```

Answer (score 0):

My environment is Windows 7 Pro x64 + WMDC x64 + WinCE 5/6 and it works fine. So I believe that WMDC does support WinCE 5.0.
As I remember WMDC can conflict with MS Outlook, try to google this, this is probably your case.

Comment: I appreciate the response - unfortunately the only applications installed on the device are MS WordPad and Internet Explorer.  Outlook is not installed on the host side either.  I was wondering if I needed to make any changes/updates on the device side after updating to Win7 and WMDC on the host side..

Comment: I used ActiveSync/WMDC on different PCs and it was fine all times. What do you see in Windows 7 Device manager when you attach your Windows CE device? Have you installed driver for your device?

Comment: It's a custom device - we didn't create a driver for it when using with ActiveSync.  Typical exchange is just ASCII text over RS232.  ActiveSync was only used for file transfer.

Comment: I think if Device Manager does not recognize your device WMDC will not work. Try to install driver: Device manager - your device - Update driver - Browse my comp - Let me pick from a list - Microsoft USB Sync

Comment: It's not connected by USB, it's connected by serial (COM1).  I will continue seeking documentation on repllog.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If connecting through a serial port, you may have to modify the registry on the host PC to allow serial connections.

Change this key to the name of the serial port, e.g. "COM1". Then reboot your PC and do not change anything in the WMDC settings dialog after that.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\SerialPort
```

Comment: SerialPort current has a value of "COM1".  I'm updating my post to include the values of the other registry keys for HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services